# navigator.getUserMedia is throwing error NotAllowedError: Invalid state

Tags: javascript, screen-capture, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Trying to create a chrome extension (manifest v.3) that can record screen. The flow is:

- Showing a record button in popup
- Clicking a record button opens an html page in background
- html page sends request to background to show desktop selector for the active tab
- User selects the window/tab and start recording

Here is the code (https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mxfsyx?file=index.html):

Created a record button in popup

```
document.querySelector('#startFromBackgroundPage')
    .addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
          { event: 'open-bg-page' }, function(response) { console.log(response); });
    });
```

Background page

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.event === 'open-bg-page') {
    chrome.tabs.create({
      url: 'index.html',
      selected: false,
    });
  }

  if (message.event === 'record') {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
          ["screen", "window"],
          tabs[0],
          function(id, options) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
              {'mediaId': id, options: options});
          });
    });
  }
});
```

index.html/app.js

```
// Send message as soon page is loaded.
setTimeout(() => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    { event: 'record' }, function(response) { console.log(response); });
}, 500);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('on message', message);
  if (message.mediaId) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      onAccessApproved(message.mediaId, message.options);
    }, 100);
  }
});
// Launch webkitGetUserMedia() based on selected media id.
function onAccessApproved(id, options) {
  if (!id) {
    console.log('Access rejected.');
    return;
  }

  var audioConstraint = {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: id
      }
  };

  if (!options.canRequestAudioTrack)
    audioConstraint = false;

  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: audioConstraint,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: id,
        maxWidth:screen.width,
        maxHeight:screen.height} }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
}

function getUserMediaError(error) {
  document.querySelector('#message').innerHTML = error;
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia() error: ', error);
}
```

But its throwing error: NotAllowedError: Invalid state

It works fine If I replace `tabs[0] with sender.tab` in background.js. But then it shows the desktop/window chooser on the background page which I don't want. I want to record the current active tab. I am handling it in background page so even the page is refresh/closed the video recording continues.

Comment: According to the MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

,this feature is deprecated.

Comment: Replacing it with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia throws Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Invalid state

Comment: Please refer to 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: It works fine If I replace tabs[0] with sender.tab in background.js

Comment: @coure2011 did u got any solution on this?

Comment: @AkbarBasha I think we need to w8 until https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/170